# how to get last date of next month in php if month have 31 days

Tags: php

**Today - 2021-03-31**

```
<?php
echo date("Y-m-t  H:i:s", strtotime("+1 month"));
?>
```

**Expected result**
2021-04-30

**Result**
2021-05-31

Answer (score 0):

Adding a month adds a certain number of days, so it throws things off. The easiest way is to get the first day of next month, then use `t` to format it to the total number of days:

```
echo date("Y-m-t  H:i:s", strtotime("first day of next month")); // 2021-04-30  10:27:35
```

Comment: I am not sure if this is the easiest solution, but you can add it to the duplicate target so that we can keep all answers in one place

Comment: I will do that, thanks.

Answer (score -1):

Should be simple as below.

```
<?php
$month_end = strtotime('last day of next month', time());
echo date('D, M jS Y', $month_end).'<br/>';

?>
```